# Debug Multiple Web API solution on localhost

Tags: c#, api, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My one webAPI solution (abc) is calling another WebAPI (xyz) solution. I am currently using localhost address to debug it. I am able to debug abc but when the call is made to xyz, I am unable to debug xyz. Is there a way where I can run both the solution at the same time on iis server in localhost?

Comment: Debug/Attach To Process?
I don't know how to tell which instance of w3wp.exe is the one you want. I just attach to all of them.

Comment: It says, unable to attach to the process. A debugger is already attached. Since I am running abc solution locally as well.

Comment: @RupertMorrish `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp` will list the worker process IDs and app pool names (under administrator). There are numerous "smart debug attach" extensions for VS if not.

Answer (score 0):

If it's under one solution, than you can try to setup multiple startup projects. In solution explorer, Right click on solution item (root item). Switch to multiple startup projects and select 2 you want to debug. Both will be running each time you run the project

[image]

Comment: They are in 2 different solution.

Comment: Then you should follow @rupert-morrish comment